# Extracting an article from the BBC website

Tags: html, wordpress, web

I want to extract an article say this:

http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-32156264

and only display the article content, so no BBC heading or footer. How would I do this? I'm thinking put it in an iFrame.

Comment: Before copy-pasting content on the interner from a big media site I suggest you to look for the legal issues on this (at least keep the references from the author)

Answer (score 1):

As you ask specifically about the BBC:

You *are* allowed to display [the RSS feed of BBC headlines](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10628494) - you could use the WordPress [RSS Links widget](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets#Using_RSS_Widgets) to do this.

You certainly *aren't* allowed to just copy someone else's story (or start removing branding etc.) – which is quite reasonable.

Note: The BBC doesn't have an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) for news, but some do - e.g. The Guardian's [Open Platform](http://open-platform.theguardian.com/) - again there will usually be strict restrictions on how you can display things, required branding, what you are/aren't allowed to change.

Correct approach: choose one or two relevant quotes you find interesting, highlight those, and make sure you have prominent link back to the original article.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there will be legal issues. Second, your page rank will be destroyed because to duplicate content. 
If you already considered the above, you should do a PHP curl request, then parse it using a regular expression to get the target data and finally post the retrieved data.

Or, you can use APIs of other news providers like williamt mentioned.